# Safe way to execute JavaScript code - on same server or another server?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, security, ubuntu

I have a website builder which allows users to drag and drop HTML blocks (`img`, `div`, etc...) into the page. They can save it. Once they save it, they can view the page.

I also allow custom code like JavaScript. Would it be safe to have their page be displayed on another server on a subdomain (mypage.example.com) but still fetched from the same database as the main server, or does it not matter to put it on the same server as the main server?

As far as I know, they cannot execute any PHP code since I will be using `echo` to display the page content.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you doing anything to sanitize the HTML, to [protect against XSS](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)?

Comment: You need to validate, escape and sanitize the user JavaScript to avoid XSS or/or CSRF.

Comment: @AndTheGodsMadeLove Would sanitizing and escaping the user's JS interfere with the code? It's really meant for tracking codes they can put into that page, like Google Analytics

Comment: `As far as I know, they cannot execute any PHP code since I will be using echo to display the page content.` - no don't do that, it's super slow: i assume the code you're talking about is `echo file_get_contents(file);`- first off, you'll be putting the entire file in RAM at once (so it uses more RAM than necessary), and the transfer does not start until the entire file has been loaded from disk (so it starts slow), use readfile() instead, it starts much faster (it starts once the first chunk has been read, instead of `all of it`), and it does both transfer and reading from disk in parallel,

Comment: which makes it faster, and it doesn't use any significant amount of ram no matter how big the file is (the same amount of ram is used for a 1KB file and a 100GB file)

Comment: @hanshenrik It's not from a file, it's from the database. I save the HTML code into the db

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your setup. If you allow them to run custom JavaScript, they can probably steal session tokens from other users, which could be used to steal other accounts. I would recommend [reading about XSS (Cross-Site-Scripting)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

In short: XSS is the vulnerability to inject code into a site, which will run on other peoples computers.

It wouldn't make sense to give you a strict tutorial on how to do this at this point, because every system is different and needs different configuration to be attack-resistant.

**Letting users put code somewhere is always a risk!**

Comment: Can they steal sessions from the main domain `example.com` if their page/code is displayed and run on subdomains like `userspage.example.com`?

Comment: @darrenfisher990: Depends on how the cookies are set. You can set them to be only availble for the main domain, but you have to make sure that you're not using wildcards like `*.example.com`

Comment: >`Letting users put code somewhere is always a risk!` i disagree. here is a great example: [sqlite.js demo page](http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/examples/GUI/), where SQLite is ported to javascript, and you're able to execute SQL directly to the sql server... running in your browser in javascript. users can execute code there, but where is the risk? the only harm a user can do there is to break the SQL db, which only exists in RAM in their own browser session, which does not affect anyone else, and to restore the db, all you need to do is to refresh the page, and you'll start with a clean db.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for another server, but you do need another domain to prevent [Cross Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attaks on your main page. and no, a subdomain [may not be sufficient](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91429/17908), put it on another domain altogether to be on the safe side. (luckily domains can be [acquired for free](http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html) if you're ok with a `.tk` domain)

> Would it be safe to have their page be displayed on another server on a subdomain

even a subdomain [could be dangerous](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91429/17908), just put it on another domain altogether, and you'll be safe.

> or does it not matter to put it on the same server as the main server?

you can have it on the same server. btw, did you know that with shared webhosting services (like GoDaddy, hostgator, etc) there's thousands of websites sharing a single physical server?

- also, DO NOT listen to the people saying you need to sanitize or filter the HTML, that is *NOT* true. there is no need to filter out anything, in my opinion, that is corruption of data. don't do that to your users, there's no need to do it. (at least i can't think of any)

> As far as I know, they cannot execute any PHP code since I will be using echo to display the page content.

correct. if you were doing `include("file");` or `eval($code);` then they could execute server-sided code, but as long as you're just doing `echo $code;`, they won't be able to execute server-side code, that's not a security issue.

Comment: If I disable cookies and session on subdomain with PHP settings, will they still be able to hijack/steal session or cookie info from main domain?

Comment: @darrenfisher990 i *think* so, yes (haven't actually tested) because you can set cookies via javascript, and they can display html with `<script>` tags that includes javascript that generates the attack cookie. (and don't think about filtering script tags, because it can be *ANY* tag, for example `<div onmouseover="javascript:create_attack_cookie();">evil div</div>`), seriously, do the safe thing: get a dedicated domain to run untrusted code. you can get a domain FOR FREE at http://dot.tk, and you can get DNS service FOR FREE at http://cloudflare.com, it doesn't have to cost you a single penny